# Python: Collecting data from the data set

Tags: python, database, dataset

I am very new Python and I am trying to analyze data from a data set.

Let's say that I have a data set of a certain food tasting. For example:

```
{'review/appearance': 2.5, 'food/style': 'Cook', 'review/taste': 1.5, 'food/type': 'Vegetable' .... }
{'review/appearance': 5.0, 'food/style': 'Instant', 'review/taste': 4.5, 'food/type': 'Noodle' ....}
```

and I have 50,000 of these entries and I am trying to find how many different types of food there are by typing in following code:

```
data = list(parseData("/Path/to/my/dataset/file"))

def feature(datum):
  feat = [datum['food/type']]
  return feat

#making a separate list of food style
foodStyle = [feature(d) for d in data]

newFoodStyle = list()

#converting the foodStyle list to just one list
for sublist in foodStyle:
  for item in sublist:
     newFoodStyle.append(item)

uniqueFood = Counter(newFoodStyle) #using counter variable to count how many unique food type there are

a = "There are %s types of food" % (len(uniqueFood))
print a

#print uniqueFood gives me 'Counter({'Noodle': 4352, 'Vegetable': 3412 and etc})
```

Now that I got how many different food types there are,
I need a lot of help on calculating the average value of 'review/taste' for each unique type of food there are in the data set.

I know there are 50k entries, so I am trying to only analyze the most reviewed food top 10.

Do I need to loop each entry and look for each uniqueFood variable and make a separate list of each uniqueFood, such as Noodle = list[] and append the following 'review/taste' number?

Any tips or ideas of how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try o use sets and set length https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `dict` type:

```
data = list(parseData("/Path/to/my/dataset/file"))

food_items = dict()
for datum in data:
    food_style = datum['food/type']
    if food_style in food_items:
        food_items[food_style].append(datum)
    else:
        food_items[food_style] = [datum]

# unique food list
unique_food = food_items.keys()


a = "There are %s types of food" % (len(unique_food))
print a

# avg 'review/taste'
avg = {
    key: sum(map(lambda i: i.get('review/taste', 0), values)) / float(len(values))
    for key, values in food_items.items()
    if values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to transform your data into pandas dataframe and then you can do sorting and averaging quite easily - example is below:

```
import pandas as pd

datalist = []

dict1 = {'review/appearance': 2.5, 'food/style': 'Cook', 'review/taste': 1.5, 'food/type': 'Vegetable'}
dict2 = {'review/appearance': 5.0, 'food/style': 'Instant', 'review/taste': 4.5, 'food/type': 'Noodle'}
dict2 = {'review/appearance': 3.0, 'food/style': 'Instant', 'review/taste': 3.5, 'food/type': 'Noodle'}

datalist.append(dict1)
datalist.append(dict2)

resultsDF = pd.DataFrame(datalist)

print(resultsDF.head())

AverageResults = resultsDF.groupby(["food/style","food/type"])["review/taste"].mean().reset_index()
print(AverageResults)
```

Results:

```
  food/style  food/type  review/taste
0       Cook  Vegetable           1.5
1    Instant     Noodle           3.5
```